# Getting dconf error while doing after ssh login on remote system

Tags: linux

Getting below error while trying to access remote system after successful login using ssh
(process:9647): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error s                                                                                            pawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=773a3303e9a9464481537a1010586                                                                                            84a --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

(process:9653): dconf-WARNING **: failed to commit changes to dconf: Error s                                                                                            pawning command line 'dbus-launch --autolaunch=773a3303e9a9464481537a1010586                                                                                            84a --binary-syntax --close-stderr': Child process exited with code 1

Pleas help to resolve this issue